# R: dataframe with unequal row lengths (empty values) into list of rows

Tags: r, list, dataframe

```
df <- data.frame(
  a= c('a',''),
  b= c('b', 'c'), 
  stringsAsFactors = F,
  row.names = c('id1', 'id2')
)

> df
    a b
id1 a b
id2   c
```

If I consider the second element in column `a` as empty (value is ''), how can I turn this dataframe into a list `l` of each row while removing the 'empty' values.

```
> l
$id1
[1] "a" "b"

$id2
[1] "c"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do a `split`

```
lapply(split(as.matrix(df), row.names(df)), setdiff, "")
#$id1
#[1] "a" "b"

#$id2
#[1] "c"
```